# Google Cloud Vision - Fails to provide good OCR on image with 2 columns of text

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

The output of double column text is not coming right order when I pass the double column text image to google cloud vision API's TEXT_DETECTION/DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION as it is taking one line from 1st column and then next line from another column and appending it.

You can see the results of the output is not aligned properly in the order they should be according to the double column. Is there a way to correct results from google vision API, or to correct it using the JSON file output?

[To view input image in JPG[click here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdnUv.jpg)

**Output-**

> 6.6 Healthcare access times. [56] impairment of their vision can use this to recognize peo- 6.6 Healthcare access ple within their vicinity
>   without them saying a word.152|| Visual impairment has the ability to
>   create consequences for health and well being. Visual impairment is
>   increasing especially among older people. It is recognized that those
>   6.5.3 Communication development individuals with visual impairment are likely to have lim- ited access to information and healthcare
>   facilities, and Visual impairment can have profound effects on the de-
>   may not receive the best care possible because not all velopment of
>   infant and child communication. The lan- health care professionals are
>   aware of specific needs re- guage and social development of a child or
>   infant can lated to vision. be very delayed by the inability to see
>   the world around them. . A prerequisite of effective health care could
>   very well be having staff that are aware that people may have problems
>   with vision. Social development Social development includes in-
>   teractions with the people surrounding the infant in the Communication
>   and different ways of being able beginning of its life. To a child
>   with vision, a smile from to communicate with visually impaired
>   clients must a parent is the first symbol of recognition and communi
>   be tailored to individual needs and available at all cation, and is
>   almost an instant factor of communication. For a visually impaired
>   infant, recognition of a parent's voice will be noticed at
>   approximately two months old, but a smile will only be evoked through
>   touch between 7 Epidemiology parent and baby. This primary form of
>   communication is greatly delayed for the child and will prevent other
>   forms of communication from developing. Social interactions The WHO
>   estimates that in 2012 there were 285 million are more complicated
>   because subtle visual cues are miss- visually impaired people in the
>   world, of which 246 mil- ing and facial expressions from others are
>   lost. lion had low vision and 39 million were blind.[4] Due to delays
>   in a child's communication development, of those who are blind 90%
>   live in the developing they may appear to be disinterested in social
>   activity with world. [56] Worldwide for each blind person, an average
>   peers, non-communicative and un-education on how to of 3.4 people have
>   low vision, with country and regional communicate with other people.
>   This may cause the child variation ranging from 2.4 to 5.5.[57] to be
>   avoided by peers and consequently over protected By age: Visual
>   impairment is unequally distributed by family members. across age
>   groups. More than 82% of all people who are blind are 50 years of age
>   and older, although they repre- sent only 19% of the world's
>   population. Due to the ex- anguage development with sight much of what
>   is pected number of years lived in blindness (blind years), learned by
>   a child is learned through imitation of others, childhood blindness
>   remains a significant problem, with where as a visually impaired child
>   needs very planned in an estimated 1.4 million blind children below
>   age 15. struction directed at the development of postponed imi- By
>   gender: Available studies consistently indicate that in tation. A
>   visually impaired infant may jabber and imitate every region of the
>   world, and at all ages, females have a words sooner than a sighted
>   child, but may show delay significantly higher risk of being visually
>   impaired than when combining words to say themselves, the child may
>   males. tend to initiate few questions and their use of adjectives is
>   infrequent. Normally the child's sensory experiences are By geography:
>   Visual impairment is not distributed uni- not readily coded into
>   language and this may cause them formly throughout the world. More
>   than 90% of the to store phrases and sentences in their memory and re
>   world's visually impaired live in developing countries. [57] peat them
>   out of context. The language of the blind child Since the estimates of
>   the 1990s, new data based on the does not seem to mirror their
>   developing knowledge of 2002 global population show a reduction in the
>   number the world, but rather their knowledge of the language of of
>   people who are blind or visually impaired, and those others. who are
>   blind from the effects of infectious diseases, but A visually impaired
>   child may also be hesitant to explore an increase in the number of
>   people who are blind from the world around them due to fear of the
>   unknown and conditions related to longer life spans. 157|| also may be
>   discouraged from exploration by overprotec- In 1987, it was estimated
>   that 598,000 people in the tive family members. Without concrete
>   experiences, the United States met the legal definition of blindness.
>   Is Of child is not able to develop meaningful concepts or the this
>   number, 58% were over the age of 65.581 In 1994- language to describe
>   or think about them. 55] 1995, 1.3 million Americans reported legal
>   blindness. 159|

Comment: FWIW I notice that ABBYY is much better at detecting columns, but not as accurate at ocr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Cloud vision supports multi-column documents and provides better reading order.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/fulltext-annotations

Answer (score -2):

You can use the DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION to find different block/paragraph and then armonize the response.

Please find here the complete reference to documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

Comment: Armonize? Is that even a word?